# Selects droplist inside ngTable loses its scope

Tags: angularjs, angular-strap, ngtable

If I put the Selects (select.js) droplist inside ngTable, and try to show the selection from outside the table, it loses its scope and doesn't show the selection. Hopefully, I was able to explain this.

Here's the preview. In the preview, you will see a select droplist which has two output locations. One inside the table which works and another outside the table which doesn't.

http://plnkr.co/edit/tQYmRrTjXOhTohsESpNo?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works. Here's what I had to do. I had to modify the angular-strap.js. Add scope.$apply() to the following piece of code.

```
$select.update = function (matches) {
  scope.$matches = matches;
  if (controller.$modelValue && matches.length) {
    if (options.multiple && angular.isArray(controller.$modelValue)) {
      scope.$activeIndex = controller.$modelValue.map(function (value) {
        return $select.$getIndex(value);
      });
    } else {
      scope.$activeIndex = $select.$getIndex(controller.$modelValue);
    }
  } else if (scope.$activeIndex >= matches.length) {
    scope.$activeIndex = options.multiple ? [] : 0;
  }
  scope.$apply();
};
```

Comment: This works, but throws an Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress.

Comment: Where is your plunker for this.  I would like to see be able to do the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

I solved your problem, and it had to do with levels of scope.

(First of all, why did you put the Select control *within* the table? They are not table data, so they don't go in the `<table>` tag.)

You were using a `ngTable` directive that created its own scope. So your Select was under two scopes, like so:

```
[DemoCtrl scope] -> [ngTable scope] -> [Select]
```

The `selectedIcon` is defined on the `DemoCtrl` scope.

You've run into a common problem. When the select looks for `selectedIcon`, it searches up the levels of inheritance and finds it. So it can read properties of parent/ancestor scopes. *But it cannot write to them*. Instead, your Select creates/changes the property on the `ngTable` scope, which is not seen by the binding outside it.

For this reason, AngularJS recommends that, instead of using *values* in `ngModel`, you reference objects. Because objects in Javascript are always by reference. So here's the fix:

Incorrect:

```
ng-model="selectedIcon"
```

Correct:

```
ng-model="obj.selectedIcon"
```

`obj` being an object you created on `DemoCtrl` scope.

The first few paragraphs explain this phenomenon well: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Comment: I have updated the preview. It still has problem showing the current selection. http://plnkr.co/edit/ThDAUj61mz2UGqCK6Grw?p=preview

Comment: Yes, so there were two problems. You've fixed the first and now you're seeing the second one.

If you notice, the outside binding is delayed -- it doesn't show the selection until it's changed again. So it's always one behind. This is usually caused when ```$scope.$apply()``` is missing from a directive's event handler.

Comment: Where would you put that $apply function?

Comment: within the dropdown directive, at the end of the event handler that handles the click which changes the dropdown selection.

Comment: How come I don't see your example filter when a selection is made from the drop down menu?